# Bouncing map back into its bounds, after user dragged it out

Tags: c#, bitwise, enum, unity3d

Users like exploring maps, seeing all that is around. However they tend to go too far. To prevent the map from getting lost to the user it bounces back into the set bounds, as defined by a rectangle.

To do this I keep track of two rectangles, the outer rectangle that the user moves around (the map), and an inner rectangle that serves as the viewport. When the outer rectangle gets swiped all the way to the right, the left side of the inner and outer rectangles overlap. The user can still drag it to see the overhang of the map, but once they release their touch the map moves back to inside the bounds.

My implementation for this: (unity 2019.1.8f1 with C# 4.x runtime IL2CPP):

**MapMover.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class MapMover : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    [Flags]
    private enum OutOfBoundsDirection { Inbounds = 1, Left = 2, Right = 4, Top = 8, Bottom = 16 };
    private OutOfBoundsDirection outOfBounds;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject mainCanvas;
    [SerializeField] private BoxCollider2D maskCol;

    private readonly float snapBackSpeed = 100;

    private Vector3 startTouchPos;
    private BoxCollider2D col;
    private WaitForEndOfFrame waitFrame;

    private void Start()
    {
        waitFrame = new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        col = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        startTouchPos = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Move the map in a 1:1 scale to the movement of the finger. To do this We need to divide the difference between the start position of the touch and the current position
    /// by the scale of the canvas (and any other parent, whose scale isn't exactly 1. Right now this isn't the case).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventData"></param>
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        var posDiff = startTouchPos - Input.mousePosition;
        transform.localPosition -= posDiff / mainCanvas.transform.localScale.x;
        startTouchPos -= posDiff;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        CheckBounds();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the map is still within the set bounds of the inner rect.
    /// </summary>
    private void CheckBounds()
    {
        Rect innerRect = new Rect(maskCol.GetCornerVertices()[3].x, maskCol.GetCornerVertices()[3].y, maskCol.size.x, maskCol.size.y);
        Rect outerRect = new Rect(col.GetCornerVertices()[3].x + transform.localPosition.x, col.GetCornerVertices()[3].y + transform.localPosition.y, col.size.x, col.size.y);

        if (outerRect.xMin < innerRect.xMin && outerRect.xMax > innerRect.xMax &&
            outerRect.yMin < innerRect.yMin && outerRect.yMax > innerRect.yMax)
        {
            outOfBounds = OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds;
        }
        else
        {
            if ((outOfBounds &= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds) == OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds)
            {
                outOfBounds ^= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds;
            }

            if (outerRect.xMin > innerRect.xMin)
            {
                outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Left;
            }

            if (outerRect.xMax < innerRect.xMax)
            {
                outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Right;
            }

            if (outerRect.yMin > innerRect.yMin)
            {
                outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Bottom;
            }

            if (outerRect.yMax < innerRect.yMax)
            {
                outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Top;
            }
            StartCoroutine(MoveInbounds());
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Translate the map to inside the bounds
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private IEnumerator MoveInbounds()
    {
        if ((outOfBounds & OutOfBoundsDirection.Left) != 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.left * snapBackSpeed);
        }
        if ((outOfBounds & OutOfBoundsDirection.Right) != 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * snapBackSpeed);
        }

        if ((outOfBounds & OutOfBoundsDirection.Top) != 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * snapBackSpeed);
        }

        if ((outOfBounds & OutOfBoundsDirection.Bottom) != 0)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.down * snapBackSpeed);
        }
        yield return waitFrame;
        CheckBounds();
    }
}
```

**BoxColliderExtensions.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;

public static class BoxColliderExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the local position of the four corner vertices of the collider
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="col">Array containing the corner points, starting at the top right and going clockwise</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Vector2[] GetCornerVertices(this BoxCollider2D col)
    {
        Vector2[] verts = new Vector2[4];

        verts[0] = col.offset + new Vector2(-col.size.x, col.size.y) * 0.5f;
        verts[1] = col.offset + new Vector2(col.size.x, col.size.y) * 0.5f;
        verts[2] = col.offset + new Vector2(col.size.x, -col.size.y) * 0.5f;
        verts[3] = col.offset + new Vector2(-col.size.x, -col.size.y) * 0.5f;

        return verts;
    }
}
```

The code works smoothly. I've never used bitmasks before but thought this would be a nice application of it, since the map can be moved out of bounds in multiple directions at the same time (e.g. up & right). But this takes a lot of if checks to do, which I feel can be halved, as i'm pretty much checking the same thing twice in `CheckBounds` and `MoveInBounds`.

I'm not experiencing any performance issues with it, so don't need to micro optimize it. Mainly looking for readability improvements/getting rid of those double ifs.

Comment: For some reason, wherever you call GetCornerVertices(), you are only using its element with the index [3]; and then both its x and y fields. Without diving deep inside the logic, this asymmetry looks suspicious: it looks like you rely on the minimap being in one specific corner of the screen, or something like this. However, if there's a valid reason to only check a single vertex, there's no need to detect the rest.

Comment: @IMil it is because of the way a rect is constructed. `new Rect(float x, float y, float width, floath height`. the vertex at index `[3]` is the bottom left vertex. Starting from this vertex means I can pass in its full width/height to get the total rectangle. If I used index [0] (top left) i'd have to pass in width/-height. As you say only that single index gets used here and could indeed make a function that returns just that specific vertex, hand't thought of that. Thanks! (If you add that as an answer I can upvote it)

Comment: Not a code review, but I find the re-positioning really bad UX (what if I want to find distance to a known landmark that is just outside of the bounds?). Better to provide a sort of "home" button to go back to the initial position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Readability

> *Mainly looking for readability improvements/getting rid of those double ifs.*

Since you are considered about readability, I will focus on that part.

---

Declare a flags enum on multiple lines and prefer to use the bit shift to indicate its location. Use an unsigned type as underlying type. Have a value corresponding to 0, because that is the default of any enum.

> ```
> [Flags]
> private enum OutOfBoundsDirection { Inbounds = 1, Left = 2, Right = 4 // ..
> ```

```
[Flags]
private enum OutOfBoundsDirection : uint
{ 
    None     = 0
    Inbounds = 1 << 0, 
    Left     = 1 << 1, 
    Right    = 1 << 2, 
    Top      = 1 << 3, 
    Bottom   = 1 << 4
}
```

---

Don't inline annotations.

> ```
>  [SerializeField] private GameObject mainCanvas;
> ```

```
[SerializeField] 
private GameObject mainCanvas;
```

---

Use early exit when you want to avoid nested if statements.

> ```
> if (outerRect.xMin < innerRect.xMin && outerRect.xMax > innerRect.xMax &&
>     outerRect.yMin < innerRect.yMin && outerRect.yMax > innerRect.yMax)
> {
>     outOfBounds = OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds;
> }
> else
> {
>     if ((outOfBounds &= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds) == OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds)
>     {
>         outOfBounds ^= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds;
>     }
>     // .. CR: code omitted for brevity
> }
> ```

```
if (outerRect.xMin < innerRect.xMin && outerRect.xMax > innerRect.xMax &&
    outerRect.yMin < innerRect.yMin && outerRect.yMax > innerRect.yMax)
{
    outOfBounds = OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds;
    return;
}
if ((outOfBounds &= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds) == OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds)
{
     outOfBounds ^= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds;
}
// .. CR: code omitted for brevity
```

---

Use `HasFlag` to perform the bit check for you.

> ```
> if ((outOfBounds & OutOfBoundsDirection.Left) != 0)
> ```

```
if ((outOfBounds.HasFlag(OutOfBoundsDirection.Left))
```

---

Create constants where you can.

> ```
> verts[0] = col.offset + new Vector2(-col.size.x, col.size.y) * 0.5f;
> verts[1] = col.offset + new Vector2(col.size.x, col.size.y) * 0.5f;
> verts[2] = col.offset + new Vector2(col.size.x, -col.size.y) * 0.5f;
> verts[3] = col.offset + new Vector2(-col.size.x, -col.size.y) * 0.5f;
> ```

```
const float factor = 0.5f;

verts[0] = col.offset + new Vector2(-col.size.x, col.size.y) * factor;
verts[1] = col.offset + new Vector2(col.size.x, col.size.y) * factor;
verts[2] = col.offset + new Vector2(col.size.x, -col.size.y) * factor;
verts[3] = col.offset + new Vector2(-col.size.x, -col.size.y) * factor;
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Is there a technical reason why a bit shift is better when declaring the enum? To me it looks likes that would be less readable on bigger enums.

Comment: No, only for readability :) But you might not agree with this. Many developers show the bit location in the declaration.

Comment: Is it considered bad style to inline annotations? I found it useful especially in Unity projects where `[SerializeField] private` is used frequently

Comment: @sonny To some point, style preferences are subjective. If you like this style, use it :) Just be consistent in what you pick.

Comment: While using constants is a reasonable suggestion, in this case replacing 0.5 with "factor" is hardly an improvement because there's no indication what this "factor" means. It would make a lot more sense to introduce two variables: "double halfWidth = col.size.x * 0.5" and its counterpart "halfHeight". Then there'll be no need to replace 0.5 with a constant, because its meaning will be obvious from the variable name.

Comment: @IMil I agree. This would be improve readability even better.

Answer (score 9):

This

> ```
>     if (outerRect.xMin < innerRect.xMin && outerRect.xMax > innerRect.xMax &&
>         outerRect.yMin < innerRect.yMin && outerRect.yMax > innerRect.yMax)
> ```

and this:

> ```
>         if (outerRect.xMin > innerRect.xMin)
>         {
>             outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Left;
>         }
>
>         if (outerRect.xMax < innerRect.xMax)
>         {
>             outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Right;
>         }
>
>         if (outerRect.yMin > innerRect.yMin)
>         {
>             outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Bottom;
>         }
>
>         if (outerRect.yMax < innerRect.yMax)
>         {
>             outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Top;
>         }
> ```

are candidates as extension methods:

```
static class Extensions
{
  public static bool Contains(this Rect outerRect, Rect innerRect)
  {
    return outerRect.xMin < innerRect.xMin && outerRect.xMax > innerRect.xMax &&
             outerRect.yMin < innerRect.yMin && outerRect.yMax > innerRect.yMax;
  }

  public static OutOfBoundsDirection Overlaps(this Rect outerRect, Rect innerRect)
  {
    OutOfBoundsDirection outOfBounds = OutOfBoundsDirection.None;

    if (outerRect.xMin > innerRect.xMin)
    {
       outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Left;
    }

    if (outerRect.xMax < innerRect.xMax)
    {
      outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Right;
    }

    if (outerRect.yMin > innerRect.yMin)
    {
      outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Bottom;
    }

    if (outerRect.yMax < innerRect.yMax)
    {
      outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Top;
    }

    return outOfBounds;
  }
}
```

---

I'm not a fan of the `OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds` flag, because it can lead to invalid states as:

```
OutOfBoundsDirection bounds = OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds | OutOfBoundsDirection.Left;
```

---

> ```
>     if (outerRect.xMin > innerRect.xMin)
>     {
>        outOfBounds |= OutOfBoundsDirection.Left;
>     }
> ```

What if `outOfBounds` has the flag `Left` set before this check, then it's still set even if `outerRect.xMin <= innerRect.xMin`? Or maybe you reset `outOfBounds` elsewhere?

Maybe the first check:

> ```
>         if ((outOfBounds &= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds) == OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds)
>         {
>             outOfBounds ^= OutOfBoundsDirection.Inbounds;
>         }
> ```

should just be:

```
outOfBounds = OutOfBoundsDirection.None;
```

Comment: I was just thinking exactly the same about `Inbounds`.

Comment: I had not thought of putting them into extension methods. It would look a lot cleaner indeed. Initially I didn't have a `.None` flag and after adding it didn't realise I can just use that now to set `outOfBounds = OutOfBoundsDirection.None` instead of the if check. Appreciate your feedback!